# LLBL: Delete Where NOT IN

Tags: .net, llblgenpro

I'm trying to perform the following query in LLBL and I'm not having much luck.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyTableId NOT IN ('39', '43', '44')
```

Essentially, I'm up to this point:

```
private static void Delete(MyTableCollection newRecs)
{
    PredicateExpression filter = new PredicateExpression();
    MyTableCollection allRecords = new MyTableCollection();

    filter.Add(new FieldCompareSetPredicate(
                   MyTableFields.MyTableId,
                   MyTableFields.MyTableId,
                   SetOperator.In, null, null, string.Empty, 0, null, true));

    allRecords.DeleteMulti(filter);
}
```

I'm not sure if the above code is correct, but I'm not understanding how I can supply newRecs as the Collection of records to use in my IN clause. Am I even close?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** I realize that I used static ID's in my SQL example, but I'm really attempting to use the ID's that are stored in the newRecs parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the "not in" to work, you've got to pass some kind of array.  Try something like this:

```
List<int> idsNotToDelete = new List<int>();
foreach (MyTableEntity ent in newRecs)
{
     idsNotToDelete.Add(ent.MyTableId);
}
PredicateExpression filter = new PredicateExpression(MyTableFields.MyTableId != idsNotToDelete)
MyTableCollection allRecords = new MyTableCollection();
allRecords.DeleteMulti(filter);
```